# Equations are not displaying when switching languages.

Tags: discussion

Suppose you have two different keyboard languages installed on your computer. Say Mongolian and English. Suppose that you type the equation in an english keyboard and you switch by mistake to Mongolian. The screen will continue on an english keyboard (it will display english characters), however, the equation will not be displayed on the "display box".

Comment: Can you add some more detail: at what moment of typing the formula do you switch the keyboard? What browser and OS are you using? Can you attach a screenshot?